# Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll even after specifying the path in VM options

Tags: java, maven, jdbc

I am getting the following error when I try to connect my Java code to SQL Server database.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:db8a3aa3-d84b-49d2-a7eb-64c4187a8309
```

I have used maven for adding the SQL Server dependency.
Any help?

Comment: Please show exactly what you did. Using the Maven dependency is not sufficient, because that does not include the required native library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downloading the [sqljdbc 6.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=11774), extract it and modify your `classpath` to include `sqljdbc_auth.dll`

It should work.